# Exclude contracts from query if type_name is not available

Tags: sql, oracle, distinct-values

I'm trying to query for all contracts which do no have certain selections on them. The current query below will return rows that do not have the 3 selections below. However, the rows will also include contracts that do NOT have the excluded type_name, but have the other available type_name.

However, what I need is, to return the contracts ONLY which do not have the 3 type_name. I want to completely exclude contracts that have the excluded type_name.

```
SELECT DISTINCT cont.*
FROM contract cont
    ,contract_info_types type
    ,contract_info info 
WHERE cont.contract_id = info.doc_id
    AND info.type_id = type.type_id
    AND type.type_name NOT IN (
        'Contract_GIU_Code'
        ,'Contract_MUI_Code'
        ,'Contract_FOB_Code'
        )
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Hi, after running your sequel, it lists all the rows for the contract that has type_name different than 'Contract_GIU_Code', 'Contract_MUI_Code','Contract_FOB_Code'. What I want is that it DOESN'T show any of these contracts. If they don't have these 3 type_names, they should NOT be shown.

Comment: Any idea how this can be done? Will be really appreciated.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking for.  Provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Hi, many thanks, I think it all worked in the end:-) Now, will it be possible to build some cases in it? Basically, I want to exclude also contracts which don't have 'Contract_GIU_Code' but have  'Contract_MUI_Code' and 'Contract_FOB_Code'

Answer (score 0):

Learn to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

In this case, I would recommend `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM contract c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM contract_info_types cit JOIN
                       contract_info i 
                       ON cit.type_id = t.type_id
                  WHERE c.contract_id = i.doc_id AND
                        cit.type_name IN ('Contract_GIU_Code', 'Contract_MUI_Code', 'Contract_FOB_Code')
                 );
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but unfortunately NOT EXISTS still shows me the contracts which DO NOT have the 3 listed contract_codes

Comment: What's this SELECT 1 doing? A typo?

Comment: @Skywalker . . . No.  `exists` selects for the existence of a row.  The row needs a column.  `1` is a column.

Comment: Ok, still doesn't filter out those contracts. I ran the exact same sequel as you wrote, with SELECT 1

Answer (score 0):

you can use `sum windows` function as follows:

```
Select distinct <column_names> from
(SELECT cont.*, sum(case when type.type_name IN (
        'Contract_GIU_Code'
        ,'Contract_MUI_Code'
        ,'Contract_FOB_Code'
        ) then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by cont.contract_id) as sm
FROM contract cont
    ,contract_info_types type
    ,contract_info info 
WHERE cont.contract_id = info.doc_id
    AND info.type_id = type.type_id)
Where sm = 0
```

Comment: Thanks for providing this. It will however still show the contracts which DO NOT have these 3 codes. In select distinct <column_names>, if I try to select from table type, it will throw an error. It seems to only work when I do SELECT DISTINCT *